# Enabling LLVM in MonoDevelop?

Tags: c#, iphone, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm trying to enable the LLVM option in MonoDevelop. [This webpage](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Runtime:Documentation:LLVM#Usage) says to pass the line `--enable-llvm=yes` to configure it.

I assume this means I should add it to the 'additional mtouch arguments' section listed under iPhone build in MonoDevelop? When I do, I get compiler errors:

> Compiling to native code
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch -v
>   --nomanifest --nosign -dev "/Users/ahmedhakeem/Documents/Projects/JabberEngine2/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/aChicks.app"
>   "-r=/Users/ahmedhakeem/Documents/Projects/JabberEngine2/ExEn/ExEnEmTouch/bin/iPhone/Release/ExEnEmTouch.dll"
>   "-r=/Users/ahmedhakeem/Documents/Projects/JabberEngine2/ExEn/ExEnCore/bin/iPhone/Release/ExEnCore.dll"
>   "-r=/Users/ahmedhakeem/Documents/Projects/JabberEngine2/MyCode/Farseer
>   Physics Engine 3.3.1
>   XNA/bin/iPhone/Debug/FarseerPhysics.dll"
>   "-r=/Users/ahmedhakeem/Documents/Projects/JabberEngine2/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/Content/Jabber.dll"
>   "-r=/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll"
>   "-r=/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll"
>   "-r=/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll"
>   "-r=/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll"
>   "-r=/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/OpenTK.dll"
>   "-r=/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.Linq.dll"
>   -nolink "-sdk=4.3" --enable-llvm=yes "/Users/ahmedhakeem/Documents/Projects/JabberEngine2/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/aChicks.exe"
>   Framework is:
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk
>   Error: You should provide one root
>   assembly only

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the 'Advanced' tab on the iPhone Build section of the project's options - on my setup there's a checkbox to enable LLVM.

I'm using MonoDevelop 2.4.2 and MonoTouch 4.03.

Answer (score 2):

The web page talks about Mono LLVM support. Things like:

> The llvm back end can be enabled by passing --enable-llvm=yes to configure.

are (mono) build related.

When using monotouch you're not using mono directly (and not building it). What you're using is the mtouch tool (directly or with MonoDevelop addin). The command lines for mtouch are different, e.g. from mtouch --help

> ```
> --llvm                 Enable the LLVM compiler
> ```

This is very similar to using llvm with mono itself (from mono --help)

> ```
> --llvm, --nollvm       Controls whenever the runtime uses LLVM to compile code.
> ```